# Datastax Cassandra Java Driver, Future Result Set appears to return in consistent data

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am using Cassandra Driver 3.0  .When I am reading data asynchronously, I am getting the data in consistent.

For example: In the given list of employee ids, [id1, id2], I am requesting  the data for id1 and id2. I am getting data for id1 and id2 and sometimes id1 and **id1**.  This is inconsistent. I have provided the code below. Can you please help?

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeShortProfile(List<String> employeeIds) throws InterruptedException,
        ExecutionException {
    List<ResultSetFuture> rsFutureList = new ArrayList<ResultSetFuture>();
    List<Employee> EmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();


    for (String EmployeeId : EmployeeIds) {

    //Please NOTE
    //preparedStatement.getbStGetShortProfileById() below in the code returns  the following prepared statement
    //client.getSession().prepare(
    //"select employee_id, company_name, company_icon_url, product_icon_image, company_display_name, employee_information, detail_description from samplekeysapce.tbl_master_employees where employee_id = ? limit 15");
    // FYI, I did not set the consistency level in the execute.

        BoundStatement bStGetShortProfileById = preparedStatement.getbStGetShortProfileById();

        logger.debug("... setting the short profile id ..."+EmployeeId);
        bStGetShortProfileById.bind(EmployeeId);
        Session session = client.getSession();
        ResultSetFuture rs = session.executeAsync(bStGetShortProfileById);
        rsFutureList.add(rs);
    }


    for(ResultSetFuture rsF : rsFutureList){
        ResultSet rs = rsF.getUninterruptibly();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = rs.iterator();
        Employee c = extractEmployee(rowIterator);
        if(c!= null){
            EmployeeList.add(c);

        }


    }
    return EmployeeList;
}
```

Comment: associated jira ticket for cross referencing: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1198

Comment: Thank you Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 0):

Olivier Michallat from the Datastax team (https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=omichallat) was able to help us point out that BoundStatement needs to be different instance each time.

We verified our code, we were not returning different BoundStatement instance.  We corrected the code on our side and the problem is resolved.

The conversation between us and the Datastax team is here https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1198.

Thanks 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis for the support.